# bootstrap 3 - collapse 'jump' behaviour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting a weird behaviour when using bootstrap's collapse feature. When collapsing and uncollapsing, the `div` presents a 'jump' behaviour.

This is shown in the **[following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuk1dbag/)**.

Here's the code

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refine-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="refine-search">
  Refine Search
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse refine-search-collapse-container well" id="refine-search">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">ad</option>
          <option value="">sfsd</option>
          <option value="">sdf</option>
          <option value="">sf</option>
          <option value="">sdf</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Blah1</option>
          <option value="">Blah2</option>
          <option value="">Blah3</option>
          <option value="">Blah4</option>
          <option value="">Blah5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Yes</option>
          <option value="">No</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="">
  <h3>Search Result</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: move the `well` class to the `form` element - there seems to be problem how does the boostrap js handle height calculation of animated element... Sucks - stuff like this is one of reasons i stay away from all boostrap-like css/js frameworks and preffer to write everything myself. - ah, even that doesn't get rid of the Search result text a little jump on expand.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **Jump** in your `collapse` is due to `.well` (`margin`) class CSS.

`.well` class adds `margin-bottom: 20px;` which causes jump when the `collapse` gets `display:none` property. And the `padding` of `.well` also plays role in this jump.

To make it `collapse` smoother, add the `.well` class inside the `.collapse` `DIV`
as shown below, and this `CSS`.

---

To escalate it quickly, `.well` class adds `margin-bottom, padding, and min-height` which causes **jump**, as it affects the box-model on `display:none`.

```css
.refine-search-collapse-container .well {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refine-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="refine-search">
  Refine Search
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse refine-search-collapse-container" id="refine-search">
  <form class="form-horizontal well">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">ad</option>
          <option value="">sfsd</option>
          <option value="">sdf</option>
          <option value="">sf</option>
          <option value="">sdf</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Blah1</option>
          <option value="">Blah2</option>
          <option value="">Blah3</option>
          <option value="">Blah4</option>
          <option value="">Blah5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Yes</option>
          <option value="">No</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="">
  <h3>Search Result</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I added some padding to the top of the element below and the jumping stopped.

Answer (score 3):

I have updated your fiddle go through below link may be it can help you.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuk1dbag/15/)

Put your `well` class with `form` element and just add below CSS

CSS Code-

```
.well{
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have any padding or margins on the collapsible element. This is what is causing the jump effect.

ie: in your case, it has additional classes which add padding and margins.

`<div class="refine-search-collapse-container well collapse">`

If you want to preserve all the current styles such as `.well` etc, it's best to wrap your existing collapsible element around another  tag and make the parent div the collapsible element,

**See updated example:**

In your case you would need a `.clearfix` on the collapsible element since it has a child that will overflow because of the `.well` class

**http://jsfiddle.net/vuk1dbag/19/**

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuk1dbag/2/) after update. Your code should be look like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refine-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="refine-search">
        Refine Search
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form class="form-horizontal collapse" id="refine-search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">ad</option>
              <option value="">sfsd</option>
              <option value="">sdf</option>
              <option value="">sf</option>
              <option value="">sdf</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">Blah1</option>
              <option value="">Blah2</option>
              <option value="">Blah3</option>
              <option value="">Blah4</option>
              <option value="">Blah5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">Yes</option>
              <option value="">No</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Search Result</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any `padding-bottom or padding-top` to those div with class .collapse. That padding makes the Jump effect

Comment: Not a relative answer

Answer (score 0):

This is an old bug that won't be fixed in version 3. Set the `margin-bottom` of the `well` to 0. You may have to set the top and bottom margins and/or padding of other elements to 0 also depending on where they are relative to what you're collapsing (in this case the well). You'll just have to play around, unfortunately.

Also, if you are collapsing/expanding several elements close to each other, and want to adjust the space between them after setting margins and/or padding to 0 (which will cram everything together), a hack that works (but which I despise using) is to put an empty `div` between them and adjust the top and bottom padding or margins of that instead.

Here's the issue on Github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12093

Answer (score -2):

Remove `well` class from this following `div`, it will work fine; no jumping effect.

```
<div class="collapse refine-search-collapse-container well" id="refine-search">
```

By default, `refine-search-collapse-container` `div` not taking any height but when click on `Refine Search` button to hide `refine-search-collapse-container` section, it takes the height of "40px". It causes the problem so this jumping issue is happened.

[image]

Comment: Better - move the well class to the form element. - looks the same, gets rid of the problem